# Azure Function App TimmerTrigger Timeout error on execution

Tags: node.js, azure-function-app, timer-trigger

I have deployed a TimerTrigger type Azure Function App with platform set to Windows, App Service Plan to Consumption plan and Runtime as Node.JS. It was working fine when I used VS Code to deploy. But when I setup a Azure Pipeline for CI/CD on Azure Repos to deploy the code directly to the function app, the function started throwing the below error:

```
Full Exception :
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException : Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.rally-confluence-function
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryHandleTimeoutAsync(Task invokeTask,CancellationToken shutdownToken,Boolean throwOnTimeout,CancellationToken timeoutToken,TimeSpan timeoutInterval,IFunctionInstance instance,Action onTimeout) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 633
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 549
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 505
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 283
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 330
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 94
```

Since then, I have not been able to find out what is the issue. I again tried to deploy the function from VS Code but still the same issue.

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

App Settings:

```
[
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~3",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "node",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

This issue has been hanging for long time so any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the function was working fine when deploy if from VS code at the beginning, I don't think there is any problem with your function.

You can configure timeout of your function app. Change the value of `functionTimeout` field from `"00:05:00"` to `"00:10:00"` in host.json of your function app.